# Accsess SessionDataSource from back end

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I have the following code from [this link](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/gantt/examples/overview/defaultvb.aspx?show-source=true), for the implementation of `Gantt chart`. it is a new method of coding for me. how can i use the same from the back end? or is it possibility to use the same with `MySQL`? am using mysql database hence it is not working for me.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="sds" Namespace="Telerik.Web.SessionDS" %>
  .......

   <sds:SessionDataSource ID="TasksDataSource" runat="server" DisplayWarning="false"
        PrimaryKeyFields="ID" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TelerikConnectionString %>"
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [GanttTasks] WHERE [ID] = @ID"
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [GanttTasks] ([ParentID], [OrderID], [Title], [Start], [End], [PercentComplete], [Expanded], [Summary]) VALUES (@ParentID, @OrderID, @Title, @Start, @End, @PercentComplete, @Expanded, @Summary)"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [GanttTasks]"
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [GanttTasks] SET [ParentID] = @ParentID, [OrderID] = @OrderID, [Title] = @Title, [Start] = @Start, [End] = @End, [PercentComplete] = @PercentComplete, [Expanded] = @Expanded, [Summary] = @Summary WHERE [ID] = @ID">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ParentID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="OrderID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Start" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="End" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PercentComplete" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Expanded" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Summary" Type="Boolean" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ParentID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="OrderID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Start" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="End" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PercentComplete" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Expanded" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Summary" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </sds:SessionDataSource>
```

Comment: You can give it a try by updating connection string and data provide for the session data source. Here is here you need changes perhaps: ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TelerikConnectionString %>" Change sql cline to whatever mysql client you have and update the connection string to connect to mysql database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SessionDataSource control is a custom control built only for the Telerik AJAX demos site. Replace it with a regular declarative data source like asp:SqlDataSource and you should be set. Just remove the PrimaryKeyFields and DisplayWarning properties as they are not part of the standard .NET classes.